# C# Form Button Padding

Tags: c#, winforms, button, text, padding

In C# Form i'am trying to make nicely looking Button but i cant get over text "padding" problem.

[Problematic Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tfHt.png)

[Desired Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTryv.png)

I already made my mind of how it should look but i just can't achieve it.
It is supposed to be Flat Button with Black Borders and "Options" text in it (like on second picture).
But some kind of "padding" hides pretty big part of the text.

Changing Font Size kinda helped but i want to perserve Button's ~16px Height and Font that small so it can fit in there is just unreadable.

I've already tried setting Button's Padding property to 0.
I was already thinking about some workaround like overriding OnPaint Event / making multiple controls (like, combine it with label) but i'am worried about performance impact.

Comment: I dont really use HTML or CSS. It's all done in C#. I didnt dont know HTML / CSS can be used within C#.

Comment: a) do not worry about performance until there is a reason. b) do not make all buttons have different sizes! c) don't reckon a tightly fitting button will survive moving the a different screen resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it with

```
class FixedButton : Button {
    public string FixedText;
    public Point TextOffset;
    /*public PointF FixedTextLocation {
        get{return new PointF( (float)(Location.X+TextOffset.X), (float)(Location.Y+TextOffset.Y) );}
    }*/

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(FixedText) ){
            e.Graphics.DrawString(FixedText, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), TextOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I found out i need to use TextOffset instead of FixedTextLocation in DrawString / DrawText (which can also be used instead of DrawString).

Comment: Controls use TextRenderer.DrawText.  Graphics.DrawString is for printers.  If you create a Brush or a Pen, you should dispose of it.

Comment: So is using TextRenderer.DrawText better than Graphics.DrawString?

Comment: Set your FixedText value to "Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii!" and see the results with DrawString.

Comment: Tried that but i don't see anything bad. Also when i try it with DrawText it looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hm I took a shot at it, this is the best I could do.

[image: Here]

I used an image with a flat button, with the border providing the grey area beyond the black border. Sort of a workaround. Whatever.

Here is the image for the button background [image: background].

And the code for the button:

```
// 
// button1
// 
this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("button1.BackgroundImage")));
this.button1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 4;
this.button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
this.button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 6.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.button1.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(94, 124);
this.button1.Name = "button1";
this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 28);
this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
this.button1.Text = "Options";
this.button1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

Comment: I'am not sure how it would work with multiple sizes. I plan to do more Buttons with different sizes and i think resizing image would be quite expensive. EDIT: I will look at it more after i will get some sleep but for now i think i'am looking for something little bit more flexible.

Comment: The button image is 2.77 KB (2,835 bytes)

Comment: Bad experience with resizing you know... but you inspired me and ill try other workaround.

Comment: good to hear, if I helped you a bit, do you might upvoting my answer?

Comment: You surely helped me with new idea so i tried to upvote your answer but it says i need atleast 15 reputation to be able to actually upvote. I'am sorry

Comment: @MatějBoubil, not upvote specifically, but you could select the checkmark next to the answer as a solution that worked for you so others know what helped or worked.  Upvoting is generic as you go along for other answers you find and help you out from other posts.  Check out Help -> Tour for other site etiquette.

Comment: His answer kinda helped me but didn't solve my problem.